# Is it possible to test *.ts files with Jest@20.x

Tags: typescript, jestjs

This is just question, because I am not able to find any info about that.

I can not use `ts-jest` because my node version is locked on `4.2.2` and `ts-jest` require at least `jest@22.x` which require `node6`

Comment: I'd _strongly_ recommend upgrading your node version, since a lot of tools are starting to drop support for it. If that's not possible for whatever reason, you could try using an earlier version of jest or ts-jest

Comment: I know, but when you work in corporation it is not so easy to upgrade tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just used `jest@21.x` and `ts-jest@21.x` and everytking works fine